# API for getting coordinates between two locations on road

Tags: coordinates, openstreetmap, geojson, geo

I'm creating a interactive traffic jam map where I want to show all active jams on a OpenStreetMap. The API where I get the traffic information from only gives me the start point of a jam, and the end point. Like below.

```
"fromLoc": {
    "lat": 52.17043,
    "lon": 5.43905
},
"toLoc": {
    "lat": 52.16757,
    "lon": 5.56571
}
```

What I want is to show a red line on the part of the road where the jam is at that moment. To do so I need all exact coordinates of the road between the start and end point (GeoJSON/KML).

I've tried to use the OpenRouteService API where I entered the start and end coordinates. It gives me back a set of coordinates, which seem to match the roads. The only problem is that it gives me the actual route for a car, including turns and roundabouts, etcetera. I just want a line between `fromLoc` and `toLoc`.

**This is what I get now**
[image]

**This is what I actually want**
[image]

I've been looking around for a solution for a while now, but I couldn't find any answer so far. So how can I get just the coordinates from point A to point B on the road without turning, etc.? Is there an API where this is possible?

Comment: Looks like one of your coordinates is located on the *other* side of a physically separated road, that's why you get these turns at the end of the route. Your coordinates don't exactly match the road of the underlying routing graph. I guess there is not much you can do in this case. Maybe split the route when you are very close to your coordinates and throw away the rest.